# System of Trigonomtric Equations

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

Please Help to solve the following problem :-
If,
$$\sin(x+y)=a$$
$$\cos(x-y)=b$$
$$a,b\in \Bbb R^+$$
Find $\tan(2x)$ in terms of a and b.

Comment: $$\tan2x=\tan(x+y+x-y)=\dfrac{\tan(x+y)+\tan(x-y)}{1-\tan(x+y)\tan(x-y)}$$

Comment: Oh god thats genius, why didnt i think of that!

Comment: @Nosrati,But the question asks for tan(2x) in terms of a and b

Comment: Write $\tan=\dfrac{\sin}{\cos}$.

Comment: @DhamnekarWinod You just use $\tan x = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$ and $\cos x = \sqrt{1-x^2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
x+y = \arcsin a\\
x-y = \arccos b
$$

then

$$
2x = \arcsin a + \arccos b \to \tan(2x) = \frac{a\sqrt{1-a^2}+b \sqrt{1-b^2}}{b^2-a^2}
$$

NOTE

$$
\tan(u+v) = \frac{\sin (u) \cos (v)}{\cos (u) \cos (v)-\sin (u) \sin (v)}+\frac{\cos (u) \sin (v)}{\cos (u) \cos (v)-\sin (u) \sin (v)}
$$

Comment: ,is your answer is equivalent to the answer given by Chris Custer?$\sqrt{1-a^2}=\cos{(x+y)}$ and$b^2-a^2=\cos^2{(x-y)}-\sin^2{(x+y)}$ am I right?

Comment: ,How did you calculate $\tan{(2x)}$? What is the use of your reference note? What are u and v?

Comment: @DhamnekarWinod In the reference note we have a trigonometric  identity.  Here $u = \arcsin a,\ \ v=\arccos b$. Now we have $\sin(\arcsin a) = a, \sin\arccos a = \sqrt{1-a^2}$ etc.

Comment: @Casareo,$\tan{(2x)}=\frac{\sin{(2x)}}{\cos{(2x)}}$ and $\sin{(2x)}=ab+\sqrt{(1-a^2)}\sqrt{(1-b^2)}$ But your numerator is $a\sqrt{(1-a^2)}+b\sqrt{(1-b^2)}$ How is that?

Comment: @DhamnekarWinod Please. Refer to me as Cesareo. We have $\tan \left(\sin ^{-1}(a)+\cos ^{-1}(b)\right) = \frac{a b}{\sqrt{1-a^2} b-a \sqrt{1-b^2}}+\frac{\sqrt{1-a^2} \sqrt{1-b^2}}{\sqrt{1-a^2} b-a \sqrt{1-b^2}}$ and after simplifivcations we have $\frac{a\sqrt{1-a^2} +b \sqrt{1-b^2}}{b^2-a^2}$

Comment: @DhamnekarWinod Are in general  $\tan(2x) = u$ and $\tan(2x) = -u$ equivalent solutions for $x$ ?

Answer (score 2):

$\cos2x=\cos(x+y+x-y)=\cos(x+y)cos(x-y)-\sin(x+y)\sin(x-y)= a\sqrt{1-b^2}- b\sqrt{1-a^2}$.

Similarly $\sin2x=\sin(x+y+x-y)=\sin(x+y)\cos(x-y)+\cos(x+y)\sin(x-y)=\sqrt{1-a^2}\sqrt{1-b^2}+ab$.

Thus...?

Note:  this works for quadrant $1$.  In $2,3$ and $4$ you need to change some signs.

Comment: You forgot to deal with the signs of the involved square roots. $\sin(z)=a$ does not automatically imply $\cos(z)=\sqrt{1-a^2}$.

Comment: well, $a.b$ are infact positive, so maybe we can ignore the signs in square root

Comment: No. The positivity of $\sin(x+y)$ does not imply the positivity of $\cos(x+y)$.

Comment: @Chris Custer, is more simplification of $\tan{(2x)}$ possible?

Comment: Nothing really jumps out at me.   You could probably get the radicals out of the denominator;   but I would just leave it.